# Dealing with duplicate characters

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, input, text

I'm making a wild west duelling game based on typing of the dead. You have a word to write in a certain amount of time. You win if you type out the word in time, you lose if you type it incorrectly/press the wrong button or if the time runs out.

Currently I've got everything working fine. A slight issue, however, is with how I'm dealing with displaying the letters you have to type on the screen.

Each character is stored into an array that is looped through and displayed on the screen. When the player presses the correct button, the corresponding display should turn red which it does most of the time. The times where it doesn't is when there are duplicate characters.

For example if I was typing the word 'dentist', when I type the first t, it won't turn red. However, when I get to the second t and press it, both turn red. I assume this is because I'm looping through each displayed character and checking to see if it's relevant input is being pressed and because there's two and I can only type one character at a time one is always false which 'overrides' the one that is true. I'm not sure how to implement a solution with how I'm currently dealing input so any help is appreciated!

Code:

```
    if (Duelling)
    {
        if (currentWord.Count > 0 && Input.inputString == currentWord[0].ToLower())
        {
            print(Input.inputString);
            string pressedKey = currentWord[0];
            currentWord.Remove(currentWord[0]);
        }
        else if (Input.inputString != "" && Input.inputString != currentWord[0].ToLower())
        {
            DuelLost();
        }
        if (currentWord.Count <= 0)
        {
            DuelWon();
        }

        foreach(Transform Keypad in keyDisplay.transform)
        {

            //print(Keypad.Find("KeyText").GetComponent<Text>().text);
            Keypad.Find("KeyText").GetComponent<Text>().color = currentWord.Contains(Keypad.Find("KeyText").GetComponent<Text>().text) ? Color.black : Color.red; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Compare the string instead of checking if they match....`if(currentWord == Keypad.Find("KeyText").GetComponent<Text>().text)`....

Comment: KeyText 's text is a single character of the word that needs to be typed. Currentword is a list of what has to be typed, not what I've already typed.

Comment: Then `currentWord.Remove()` is going to remove the first occurrence of whatever you pass it, which may not be the same as the first element in the list.

Comment: What? Currentword is set at the start. It is the word I have to type split up into individual characters. I remove the first index because you have to press the letters in order.

Comment: At the start? This code is running in a per-frame context as implied by your use of Input.inputString so my 1st thought was that your removal logic is off. Point taken tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue lies in your colour-updating logic. `Contains` naturally returns true if your array, well, *contains* the text you're looking for. Since the second T in "dentist" is still present in the array after you type the first one in, the component isn't going to change its colour. When inputting the second T, all instances of Ts are cleared from the list, and since you loop over all of your Text components all the time, both of them will become red.

No offence, but you're going about this rather... crudely. Allow me to suggest a more elegant method:

```
public String currentWord;

private List<Text> letterViews = new List<Text>();
private int curIndex = 0;

void Start() {
    // Populate the list of views ONCE, don't look for them every single time
    letterViews = ... // How you do this is entirely up to you
}

void Update() {
    // ...

    if (Duelling) {
        // If we've gone through the whole word, we're good
        if (curIndex >= currentWord.Length) DuelWon();

        // Now check input:
        // Note that inputString, which I've never used before, is NOT a single character, but
        // you're using only its first character; I'll do the same, as your solution seems to work.
        if (Input.inputString[0] == currentWord[currentIndex]) {
            // If the correct character was typed, make the label red and increment index
            letterViews[currentIndex].color = Color.red;
            currentIndex++;
        }
        else DuelLost();
    }
}
```

I daresay that this is a much simpler solution. `DuelWon` and `DuelLost` shall reset the index to 0, clear the text in all `letterViews` and turn them back to black, perhaps.

How to populate the list of views: you can make it public and manually link them by hand through the inspector (boring), or you can do it iteratively using `Transform.GetChild(index)`. You've probably got enough Text views to accommodate your longest words; I recommend filling the list up with them all. You only do it once, you lose no performance by doing so, and you can re-use them for any words in your dictionary.